# Can't install El Capitan over beta version

Tags: macos

I saw a previous question similar to mine but no answer. I participated in the beta version of El Capitan I think last year. When the public release version came out I installed it and didn't discover that I was still using the Beta version until a month ago. I can't seem to find a way to do so. Apple tech support wants to charge me ridiculous $'s to help me with no guarantees. Can anyone send me to a site or tech paper or direct help to help get rid of the beta? I am unable to update from the app store. I am using a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012). Thanks

Comment: Why are you unable to update from the App Store? What happens when you try?

Comment: Thanks for responding Tetsujin. I have version 10.11 Beta (15A278b) installed. When I try to install from the apps page (OS X El Capitan GM Candidate) it says OS X v10.11 is already installed on this computer. Use the Updates page to install the 10.11 update or if you would like to download the full OS X installer click Continue. What is a GM Candidate? Until I find out I don't want to download the full installer. Do you know if that is a safe installer?

Answer (score -1):

GM is a Master update (the last one before the real thing).
Your literature when participating in the beta testing has a paragraf how to go from beta to the final release.

Comment: Thanks, LexS, I remember that it did but couldn't find it in my email from a year or so ago. I went ahead and tried the GM install. It took six hours to download, but it and the following two updates seemed to have worked! I am now at version 10.11.2. Everything seems to be working the same right now. Thanks all of you.